# Unable to perform getServerSideProps within _app.js for nextjs

Tags: next.js, next-auth

Was hoping to better understand how to use such a function in order to get session information or even consider where to put my Navigation component.

Currently I have my navigation nested in _app.js file as

```js
<NavBar />
<Component {...pageProps} />
```

and I am trying to get session information from the server as I wish to make sure the navigation shows signin/signout depending on the user session information such as

```js
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  console.log("index getting session");
  try {
    const session = await getSession(context);

    return {
      props: {
        session,
      },
    };
  } catch (error) {
    return {
      props: {
        session: null,
      },
    };
  }
}
```

P.S - console.log() on top does not run

Is this incorrectly done? If anyone has a better recommendation or where I should put my Nav in order to make sure it can perform getServerSideProps for authentication purpose.

Appreciate all the help. Spend more than a day on it with many pointing me in the direction of Next-Auth problem such as `NEXT_PUBLIC_SECRET` not set correctly or `NEXTAUTH_URL` not set correctly but I feel that it might be the `getServerSideProps` instead

Comment: just curious. where are you looking for the message? in the client or server?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call `getServerSideProps` in the *App.js* file, have a look [here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/10874#discussioncomment-1085)

> It'll be introduced later, but we need to figure out the semantics as we really don't want getServerSideProps in _app to opt-out static generation for all pages

If you want to make the navigation shows signin/signout depending on the user session information, then one solution is to call the session from the `<NavBar/>` component, you don't have to call it from server side and pass it to one component you can simply get advantage of [`useSession()`](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/client#usesession) and call it from inside your `<NavBar/>` component to have access to the session data.

> ### useSession()
>
> . Client Side: Yes 
>  . Server Side: No
> The useSession() React Hook in the NextAuth.js client is the easiest way to check if someone is signed in.
> Make sure that <SessionProvider> is added to pages/_app.js

```js
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react";
//...
const NavBar = () => {
const { data: session, status } = useSession()
//...
}
```

Now based on `status` you decide what button to display in your JSX:

```js
{status === "authenticated" ? <SignOutButton/> : <SignInButton/>}
```

If you want to access the session from a server componet you have to use [`getServerSession()`](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/nextjs#getserversession) method instead.